# Not sure if EditText or KeyEvent are not listening or is an XML problem

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a game but I need the user to fill in the username before jumping from Main Activity to Activity 2.
If the username is empty, itdoesn't do anything.
If the username has at least one letter, it launches second activity.
In my case it never works and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
This is my code.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText et1;
    TextView tv1;
    String usuario;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
        tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        /*Button next = findViewById(R.id.boton);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });*/

        et1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                usuario = et1.getText().toString();
                if(et1.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                        startActivity2();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


    }
 public boolean startActivity2(){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        return false;
    }
```

And the activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/texto"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:background="#ff8200"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="jump"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:ems="7"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxLength="11"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried for the ifs !isEmpty(), trim(), !equals and absolutely nothing.

Here is the manifest, if necesarry.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.juegocartas3">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JuegoCartas3">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity3"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText et1;
    TextView tv1;
    String usuario;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        
        et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
        tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        et1.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                if ((actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION) == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    usuario = et1.getText().toString();

                    if (usuario.trim().length() > 0) {
                        startActivity2();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Please add User name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

   public void startActivity2() {
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I attempted it and it doesn't work either. I believe at this point to be a software problem since so many times it should have worked. Thanks a lot for answering my question once again.